# Using EntityDataSource in "Tracing and Caching for Entity Framework"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, caching, objectdatasource

I am using [Tracing and Caching for Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) in my asp.net 4 application. It works great when I work on my entities manually, but in master-detail pages that have a gridview and an entitydatasource, I cannot make entitydatasource use the global cache because I have no control over creating objectcontext and entitydatasource does all the work by itself.

My question is: is there a way to customize entitydatasource for initializing the object context and things like that and if not how can i use and objectdatasource with entity faramework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. `EntityDataSource` offers event `ContextCreating`. If you handle this event you will be able to initialize context yourselves and pass it to data source via event's arguments.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. you saved me hours of converting all of my entitydatasources to objectdatasources.